# WCF multip proj app and app.config contracts

Tags: wcf

On my dev box I have a solution with 6 projects.  It is a WCF(3 proj) and multiple biz projects (other 3).

When I copy the core WCF folder, it's bin and web.config I get an error message on the server saying that it cannot find the contract that is stated in the app.config  section of the biz app with an app.config.

Where should I put this app.config?   I tried to add the  node to the web config but no go there.

Comment: Where that services supposed to run? Into a web application?

Comment: I have this 
<client> 
      <endpoint address="http://10.10.8.126:8080/grandjury/CaseJacketService"
        binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CaseJacketPortBinding"
        contract="CIMS.SC.DivisionAssignmentJSS.GrandJuryService.CaseJacket"
        name="CaseJacketPort">
        <identity>
          <dns value="ourValue" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
</client>

since I found it needed it early on.  I thought that I needed another app.config.

Comment: please update your original question with additional info - in the comments, it's **REALLY HARD TO READ** - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to host that services into a web application, you'll need to merge manually that individual `app.config` files (one for each WCF project) into your `web.config` file, under `<system.serviceModel>` section.

**EDIT**: You'll need something like this into your host configuration (web project?)

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="YourCompany.YourProject.YourService"
       behaviorConfiguration="YourBehaviorConfiguration">
      <endpoint address=""
                binding="wsHttpContextBinding"
                contract="YourCompany.YourProject.IYourService" />
      <endpoint address="mex"
                binding="mexHttpBinding"
                contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>
  </services>

  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="YourBehaviorConfiguration">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: I had already had that, see above.  Sorry I hit the wrong add comments section.

Comment: I read your example and agree that is needed to PRESENT from the WCF to the outside.

My problem is a pointer to another WS written in java by my business class that will NOT EXPOSE this java evnvironment's identity.

So I believe that I need inside the <system.servicemodel> a <client>
<endpoint ...../>
</client>

Which I have.  In the binding section I include that custom binding.

I have only one serviceBehavior much like yours.

Comment: where that java app came from? =)
can you please to edit your question to provide more detail?

Comment: I went and looked at the WCF web.config and it was different from my apps?  I replaced bad with working and poof it works as expected.

Thanks for the replies.